CMS Permissions Groupings
I have beeen asked to conduct analysis of the current permissions groups within Drupal CMS of a global insurance company's website. The goal is to understand the existing permissions structure, document what each group allows a publisher to do, identify any differences between groups, create a copy of the publisher list with associated permissions groups, and document any issues with the current permissions setup.
Please help with how to go about this analysis.
Thanks

Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a question-and-answer site where useful posts are updated. In that way it is different than a forum. Open-ended questions are not allowed. To that end, you have to actually ask a question here, it must be specific, and it must garner answers that are fact-, rather than opinion-, based.

You can go to Admin -> People -> Permissions to see a table cross referencing roles, and the permissions each role has. Note however that you will not find documentation as to what each of these permissions do - they are arbitrarily created by developers, and it's up to the developer as to how and when that permission will be enacted. Generally, they are named descriptively, but if there is any ambiguity, it requires testing to determine what the permission does, rather than referencing documentation.
A significant part of Drupal development is running tests to make sure the people that are supposed to be able to do something are able to do it, and that anything that should be restricted to a given set of users, is only accessible to those users. This requires experience, testing, and knowledge - which generally means the participation of the developer of the site.
